# How can I shut down an ethernet interface but not the attached virtual interface?

Tags: network-programming, ip, embedded-linux

I have an linux embedded machine that has a ethernet interface with a working network configuration. Also on this interface runs a second virtual network.
The config file reads as follows:

```
auto lo eth0 eth0:1

# loopback interface
iface lo inet loopback

# ethernet
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.1.0
        broadcast 192.168.1.255
        gateway 192.168.1.2

# ethernet
iface eth0:1 inet static
        address 123.123.123.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 123.123.123.0
        broadcast 123.123.123.255
        gateway 123.123.123.2
```

Now I need to bring down the eth0 device but still be able to reach the eth0:1 device.

How can this be done?
I tried to simply flush the ip address of the eth0 device, which works with the following command `ip addr flush eth0`. This works but it seems the services (webserver etc) are still listening on this interface...

Comment: Are you sure your services are bound to the eth0:1 address and not to any/all addresses?

Comment: eth0:1 is not network device it is alias ip interface over the networking device eth0. When you shut down eth0 you shutdown all ip interfaces including eth0:1. About binding - how do you know that "webserver still listening on this interface"?

Comment: Thanks guys. I seem to have misunderstood the concept of virtual network devices and aliases. I got this working using a mixture of `ifconfig` and `ifup` commands. The eth0 interface gets reconfigured using `ifconfig` with the IP of eth0:1. So eth0  is not brought down but deconfigured. It works. Eth0 is brought up using `ifup  -f eth1`